# Three Rail Decrypt when rails are different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im having a ton of trouble trying to figure out how to get my decrypt function to work. It works in ideal cases where the msg is divisible by 3, but after that i am totally lost. I have a vague idea of what i have to do because i was able to get this to work with two rails, but there are more possibilities with three rails. Im quite lost :( Also all those print statements are just to try and help me figure out what is going on.

```
import sys

def main():
    plaintext="abcdefgh"
    print(threeRailEncrypt(plaintext))
    print(threeRailDecrypt(threeRailEncrypt(plaintext)))


def threeRailEncrypt(plaintext):
    ciphertext=""
    rail1=""
    rail2=""
    rail3=""

    for i in range(len(plaintext)):
        if i%3 == 0:
            rail1=rail1+plaintext[i]
        elif i%3 == 1:
            rail2=rail2+plaintext[i]
        else:
            rail3=rail3+plaintext[i]

    ciphertext=rail1+rail2+rail3

    return(ciphertext)

def threeRailDecrypt(msg):
    if len(msg)%3==0:
        third=len(msg)//3
        print(third)
        rail1=msg[:third]
        rail2=msg[third:third*2]
        rail3=msg[third*2:]
        print(rail1,rail2,rail3)
        dm=""
        for i in range(third):
            dm=dm+rail1[i]
            dm=dm+rail2[i]
            dm=dm+rail3[i]
    else:
        third=(len(msg)//3)+1
        print(third)
        rail1=msg[:third]
        rail2=msg[third:third*2]
        rail3=msg[third*2:]
        print(rail1,rail2,rail3)
        dm=""
        for i in range(third):
            dm=dm+rail1[i]
            print(dm)
            dm=dm+rail2[i]
            print(dm)
            dm=dm+rail3[i]
            print(dm)
            if  len(rail2)>len(rail3):
                dm=dm+rail2[-1]
        return(dm)
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can slice strings (or any other sequence) using a stride; you can select every 3rd character with that:

```
def threeRailEncrypt(plaintext):
    return plaintext[::3] + plaintext[1::3] + plaintext[2::3]
```

To reverse the trend, slice up the ciphertext into three chunks and use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to recombine them again:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

def threeRailDecrypt(ciphertext):
    stride, remainder = divmod(len(ciphertext), 3)
    # how large was each of the three sections?
    sizes = [stride] * 3
    for i in range(remainder):
        sizes[i] += 1
    # slice ciphertext up into 3 sections again
    pos = 0
    pieces = []
    for s in sizes:
        pieces.append(ciphertext[pos:pos + s])
        pos += s
    # recombine the triplets
    return ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*pieces, fillvalue='')))
```

Demo:

```
>>> threeRailEncrypt('Foo bar baz and all')
'F raa lob znaoab dl'
>>> threeRailDecrypt(threeRailEncrypt('Foo bar baz and all'))
'Foo bar baz and all'
```

The last part without `zip_longest` would be:

```
# recombine the triplets
plaintext = []
for i in range(len(parts[0])):
    for part in parts:
        try:
            plaintext.append(part[i])
        except IndexError:  # part too short
            pass
return ''.join(plaintext)
```

Comment: I havent learned about izip_longest in class so i dont think i can use that method.

Comment: @user2807779: the alternative is to loop over `range(len(pieces[0]))` and use that as an index into each of the 3 pieces.

Comment: ^ can you explain this a little more? how do i get pieces? also what does the 0 value do?

Comment: @user2807779: see the update; `pieces[0]` is the first of the three ciphertext chunks.

Comment: the second method also seems to be using commands i have not learned, do you know of any others?

Comment: @user2807779: you mean `''.join()`? Just make `plaintext` a string then; `plaintext = ''` and use `plaintext += part[i]` each loop, then `return plaintext`.

Comment: @user2807779: the `try` block can be replaced with `if len(part) > i:`, drop the `except ...: pass`.

Comment: @user2807779: but I am not going to dumb this down any further; at some point you'll have to start looking up what it all means in the tutorials.

Comment: no i mean i think i understand, i just dont want my teacher to be upset that i am using things i havent learned in class explicitly so i have a limited toolkit

Comment: Sure, but at some point you'll have to do the translation to even simpler constructs yourself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code is how I decoded the cypher. It obviously assumes that you already have an encryption function. It decrypts by running the encrypt function until it results in the original input. It then runs the encryption algorithm n - 1 times, which results in the decoded message.

```
 def decrypt(msg:str)->str: 
        num = 0
        i = 0
        attempt = msg
        while i == 0:
            attempt = encrypt(attempt)
            if attempt == msg: 
                i = 1
            else: 
                num += 1
        for x in range(num):
            msg = encrypt(msg)
        return msg
```